# How to detect mobile scroll motion without touch the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, scroll, touch-event

I have a jquery that can show and hide advertisement on my website when ever the user is scrolling to a certain point in that page.  It's working on desktop but on mobile, to make it work, I have to scroll without remove my finger from the screen.  Whenever my finger is remove from the screen, then the code is no longer recognise the scroll.

My question, how to detect the scroll when my finger is off the screen but the screen is still scrolling?

```
   $window.on('scroll', goScroll);
   $(document.body).on('touchmove', goScroll);
```